# Code Signing Certificates for OSX application using Adobe AIR SDK

Tags: macos, flash, air, flash-builder

Please someone help me how it possible to create apple certificate .p12 for OS application code sign using Adobe Air SDK.

Actually i want distribute app for the App Store for example if i have used local p12 certificate I'm getting code sign not object all time and secondly when try to upload app on the app store sandbox error.

So actually i want to know a way how i can create OS X .p12 certificate for Adobe Air desktop.

Thanks

Comment: I've not done any OSX dev with Flex/AIR, but I'm assuming the certificate process is similar to iOS dev.  This article assumes you're using Flash Builder, but the steps for getting the code signing cert in .p12 format from Apple should be the same.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS064a3073e805330f6c6abf312e7545f65e-8000.html

Answer (score 0):

Like Bill Turner said, if you want to get a .p12 to distribute through the App Store you'll have to follow a similar process of signing up for the Apple Developer Program. When generating certficates, you'll have to select "macOS" instead of "iOS, tvOS, watchOS" on the Apple Developer portal: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS064a3073e805330f6c6abf312e7545f65e-8000.html

If you already have your developer's certificates, there's a short guide titled *Converting a developer certificate into a P12 file* at
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-371badff126abc17b1f-7fff.html which will let you create a .p12 file.

Also, that's just the first step, there is a guide at https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/posting-air-app-mac-app.html that walks you through the process of getting the AIR app ready for the App Store since there are a few steps you have to do manually. It also mentions that you use a self-signed certificate, you could get a warning message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a member of the Apple developer program.

You need separate certificates for iOS and Mac App Store, as well as a totally different pair to sign OSX apps to pass Gatekeeper.

For OSX you can not sign your app like you do for any other platform. You must use apples own signing facility and go through all the hoop, because Apple requires separate signing of the inner application and outer installer, as well as the air runtime separately.